# XSLT Is there a nice method to Filter

Tags: xml, xslt, filter

I am trying to filter a record set, and i have got it to work with the following XSLT, but it doesnt look nice at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response" exclude-result-prefixes="r">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Response">
            <xsl:element name="rcode">
                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="rmesage">
                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="payload">

                <xsl:for-each select="Response/payload/globalBuy[season='A09']">

                    <xsl:element name="season"><xsl:value-of select="season"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="productId"><xsl:value-of select="productId"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="globalBuyFlag"><xsl:value-of select="globalBuyFlag"/></xsl:element>

                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In addition i am seeing issues when a namespace pops up in the root. Sample XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<Response xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">
    <payload>
        <globalBuy>
            <season>CD12</season>
            <productId>123456</productId>
            <globalBuyFlag>XXL</globalBuyFlag>
        </globalBuy>
    </payload>
</Response>
```

Comment: You are referring to **globalBuyFlagResponse** in your XSLT, but **Response** in your sample XML. Which one is correct?

Comment: Sorry thank you for pointing that out! Thats what you get when you playing with multiple files at once! I have altered the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certain simplify your code by removing all the uses of **xsl:element**. Unless you want the element name to be dynamically generated, it is much simple to just write out the element as normal XML. So instead of writing this....

```
<xsl:element name="rcode">
    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Just write this...

```
<rcode>0</rcode>
```

As for filtering, if all you want to do is copy the XML, but only including certain items that match the filter, then you could override the identity template, and have templates matching the items you **don't** want to include, and simply ignore them.

Try this simplified XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Response">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
         <rcode>0</rcode>
         <rmesage>0</rmesage>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="globalBuy[not(season='A09')]" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<Response>
   <payload>
      <globalBuy>
         <season>CD12</season>
         <productId>123456</productId>
         <globalBuyFlag>XXL</globalBuyFlag>
      </globalBuy>
      <globalBuy>
         <season>A09</season>
         <productId>123456b</productId>
         <globalBuyFlag>XXLb</globalBuyFlag>
      </globalBuy>
   </payload>
</Response>
```

Then the following is output

```
<Response>
   <rcode>0</rcode>
   <rmesage>0</rmesage>
   <payload>
      <globalBuy>
         <season>A09</season>
         <productId>123456b</productId>
      <globalBuyFlag>XXLb</globalBuyFlag>
   </globalBuy>
   </payload>
</Response>
```

Do note I removed all namespaces in this example to keep things simpler.

**EDIT:** If you do want to handle a default namespace, in XSLT 1.0 you would have explicity refer to the namespaces for each element you are matching. You would do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response" exclude-result-prefixes="r">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/r:Response">
      <xsl:copy>
         <rcode xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">0</rcode>
         <rmesage xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">0</rmesage>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="r:globalBuy[not(r:season='A09')]" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder; I'm not sure what aspect of your code you don't find pretty. But I would start by rewriting it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Response>
        <rcode>0</rcode>
        <rmesage>0</rmesage>
        <payload>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Response/payload/globalBuy[season='A09']/
                                    (season, productId, globalBuyFlag)">
        </payload>
    </Response>

</xsl:template>
```

The xsl:copy-of expression uses XPath 2.0; if you want an XSLT 1.0 solution you'll have to put the xsl:for-each back in.

As regards the namespace, just google for "XSLT default namespace" and you'll find a million posts explaining your error.